# Change lxc container directory

Tags: containers, lxc

Can I change the directory where lxc containers are initialized and kept? Now they are created under /var/cache/lxc, and I would like to have them in another directory, on another partition where I have more space. Changint the mounting point of the partition is not an option as it's already used for something else.

Comment: You could also use a symlink or provide the option --lxcpath to the lxc-commands.

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can. The `/var/cache/lxc` prefix is hardcoded into every `/usr/share/lxc/templates/` template. You can change the path over there.
In case you're building LXC from sources, then the path is actually `@LOCALSTATEDIR@/cache/lxc/` where `@LOCALSTATEDIR@` is by default `--prefix=` + `/var` or `--localstatedir` you pass to `./configure`.

As for `/var/lib/lxc`, the default path to containers, specific container, and path to container's *dir* type of datastore could be configured at multiple levels:

1. `lxc.lxcpath` in `/etc/lxc/lxc.conf`, consult `man lxc.system.conf` for details.
2. `lxc-*` tools accepts `-P` flag to specify alternate container path.
3. `lxc-create` `-B dir` backing store has optional `--dir ROOTFS` flag.

Also, I highly recommend a series of [blog posts](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/20/lxc-1-0-blog-post-series/) by Stéphane Graber and [Containers storage](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/27/lxc-1-0-container-storage/) specifically.

Answer (score 1):

The least painful would be probably just `mount -o bind` a directory on the partition with space to `/var/lib/lxc` or `/var/lib/lxd` whichever is your case. This works from `/etc/fstab` too.

Answer (score 1):

For debian template (and some others) you can use environment variable, for example:

```
LXC_CACHE_PATH=/usr/share/lxc/cache
```